# How to Nginx upstream on single server with additional IP addresses added to NIC?

Tags: nginx, proxy, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, http

I am having a single dedicated server (static IP) with two additional IP addresses added.

When I run SSH with command:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

I got this result:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
    address 12.34.56.78
    netmask 255.255.255.192
    gateway 12.34.56.193

auto eth0:1
  iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 12.34.99.123
    netmask 255.255.255.255

auto eth0:2
  iface eth0:2 inet static
   address 34.51.230.56
   netmask 255.255.255.255
```

They are both static IP.

What can I do with them? They are used for NS like ns2.example.com and ns3.example.com, while ns1.example.com is the IP address 12.34.56.78 is the main web server (dedicated).

I wonder if is there any way to use the IP addresses 12.34.99.123 and 34.51.230.56 as a proxy or load balancing on my Nginx web server?

Or, as while being used as nameservers ns2 and ns3 (open ports like 53, 80, 443, 110, 25, 993 ...) just for round-rubin DNS resolve?

I am trying to figure out http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html, but do not get it right.

I am using mostly WordPress sites and few custom made PHP CMS applications over different domains - all of them on the same server.

Or do I have to have two servers for load balancing, meaning that the real servers needed to be for the stated IP addresses, instead being just static?

Maybe some links to example configuration or elese would appreciate.

I do not get it how it's done like:

```
upstream backend {
    server backend1.example.com       weight=5;
    server backend2.example.com:8080;
    server unix:/tmp/backend3;

    server backup1.example.com:8080   backup;
    server backup2.example.com:8080   backup;
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

Thank you for help and suggestion.

Comment: IP addresses don't magically make resources appear out of nowhere.

Comment: Well, I suppose that means I need at least two servers, right?

Comment: It is not a good idea to run domain's name servers on a single machine. When that machine goes down, all your domain services will be gone. You should use proper DNS hosting instead.